# shrink the middle of my navigation bar image in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made myself a navigation bar image with a width of 1920 pixel.

[image]

I would like to have the middel of that image to become smaller when the screen resolution comes smaller. Now with the default bootstrap col's the whole image shrinks and my corners become very small

example of what happens now when i shrink:

[image]

*What would be the best practice to keep the corners and still resize this image to other resolutions. (resize the middle?)*

Extra info:
I cannot set the image as background `background: url("./imgs/navbg.png")` because the image has to be transparent on top of an wooden background. so i play a little with z-index to put my navigation buttons on top.

Comment: as I know you can't resize image from the middle. but the only thing I know is that you can have two corners as images and the center of your `div` as a colored box. I am going to show you how to do it with a little trick

Comment: i ws thinking what @Afshin said... Three images and ditch the bootstrap column class all together.

Answer (score 0):

your html code:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="m-left"></div>
    <div class="m-center">
        <!-- here it goes your menu items -->
    </div>
    <div class="m-right"></div>
</div>
```

and your css code:

```
.menu {
    width:678px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999;    
}

.menu div {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}

.m-left {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/zCF8RrX.png') no-repeat;
    width:89px;
    height:69px;    
}

.m-center {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/YeDTSYe.png') repeat-x;
    width:500px;
    height:69px;
}

.m-right {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/I8NSlTn.png') no-repeat;
    width:89px;
    height:69px;    
}
```

what it looks like in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/697r7tx4/1/

Comment: Thanks this works fine. But now i am having some troubles with bootstrap and responsiveness... I would like `m-left` and `m-right` to be fixed and `m-center` to be responsive but for some reason it is not fully working. I will try to fix it in a way... The only thing i want to accomplish is that the image in `m-left` and `m-right` is not pressed together when downsizing and the corners are not small and uggly

Comment: It's not going to be problem, as if you change the specified width in pixel to percent. if you just put `.menu` div inside a bootstrap container, and remove it's width, then you can change `.m-center`s width to 100% to be a responsive div.

Answer (score 0):

Because it had to be responsive i fixed it with another method. I made one image for every `@media` and used the css trick `background-position: center`. When you work responsive this looks the best way, correct me if i'm wrong...

example code:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {.navbg{background: url('../imgs/Menu-992px.png') no-repeat;height:69px;background-position:center;}}
@media (min-width: 992px) {.navbg{background: url('../imgs/Menu-1200px.png') no-repeat;height:69px;background-position:center;}}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {.navbg{background: url('../imgs/Menu-1920px.png') no-repeat;height:69px;background-position:center;}}
```